# Private value can still be accessed from outside

Tags: swift, class, scope

I am still bit confused about the scope, I think the variables can only be accessed within its scope, that's what I've understand in a general way

```
class Car {
    let manufacturer: String

    private(set) var color: String

    init() {
        manufacturer = "Ford"
        color = "Black"
    }

    func changeColor(color: String){
        self.color = color
    }
}

var carOfTim = Car()

carOfTim.changeColor("Red") // only "changeColor" fun can update the color
print(carOfTim.color)


//why I can do this?
carOfTim.color = "Green"
print(carOfTim.color) // it prints the "Green"!
```

**Question:** I think the private variable `color` can only be accessed by the`changeColor` function, because `changeColor` has the same scope with `color`. But `carOfTim.color = "Green"` can still update the color variable, why?

**Guess**: Since I used the Xcode playground, everything is inputted into the same plain "terminal", therefore all of them might have the same scope, if I put the Car class into a different folder, `carOfTim.color = "Green"`  may not working anymore.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, `private` is scoped to the *source file*, not to the declaring entity. That's a design decision.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html):

> Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality.

...

> NOTE
>
> Private access in Swift differs from private access in most other languages, as it’s scoped to the enclosing source file rather than to the enclosing declaration. This means that a type can access any private entities that are defined in the same source file as itself, but an extension cannot access that type’s private members if it’s defined in a separate source file.

And in the examples below (bold is mine):

> However, the access level for the numberOfEdits property is marked with a **private(set)** modifier to indicate that **the property should be settable only from within the same source file** as the TrackedString structure’s definition.